# How to get rowname in every single page in Excel file using python?

Tags: python, excel

I have a dataframe which has over thousands of rows in it.Then i am sending it to an Excel file using `to_excel()` And then I am printing a copy(Hardcopy) of the Excel file.As its a table the row name are only on the first page so its hard to figure which row is which in second or any other page.Is there any way so that I can get row names in every single page using python.(I am talking about a `.xlsx` file not `.csv`).Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either you can programatically add a new column with row numbers, or you can go to page layout and ennable print headings.  When you enable print heading, you will have the row numbers, but you will also have the Columns (A, B, C) getting printed.  If that is ok then, using openpyxl it would look something like this.

```
openpyxl.worksheet.page.PrintOptions(horizontalCentered=None, verticalCentered=None, headings=None, gridLines=None, gridLinesSet=None)
```

All the None values are editable.  So in this case it would look like this. **heading=True**

```
openpyxl.worksheet.page.PrintOptions(horizontalCentered=None, verticalCentered=None, headings=True, gridLines=None, gridLinesSet=None)
```

Further information and reading can be found [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.page.html)

Comment: Thanks sir for your answer but this is not working

Comment: whats the error msg ....     what package are you using to access the excel file ?  the above can be used assuming you are using openpyxl package.